# What type of index should i create?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Table has 6 columns. `column1` is unique, so I created the primary key on `column1` and created non-clustered index for all columns:

```
         create primary key for column1
         create index for col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col1
```

So I have any column in where clause will use the index except column1 after that it takes missed column1 in primary key  and will integrate both result . because of this it will increase the performance right ?

Comment: So you now have **one non-clustered index** that is made up from **all columns**? OK -this *might* be used for queries which use `col2`, or other queries that use `col2, col3` - or queries that use **all** columns - but it can ***NEVER EVER*** be used for a query that need `col3, col4` - because those two columns **ARE NOT** the **n left-most columns** in that index! Also: adding **all columns** to an index is always a really bad idea - it basically duplicates all data, and can rarely yield any userful results....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **compound** index made up from multiple columns can **only** ever be used if the *n left-most columns* in that index are being used in a where clause.

So if you have an index on `(col1, col2, col3, col4)`, that index *might* be used

- when your query has `WHERE` conditions on all four columns
- when your query has `WHERE` conditions on `col1`, `col2`, `col3`
- when your query has `WHERE` conditions on `col1`, `col2`
- when your query has `WHERE` conditions on `col1`

but it **CANNOT** ever help you if your query has where conditions on e.g. `col3, col4` (because those are **NOT** the 2 left-most columns in the index)

So in your case, you would need an index with

- `col1, col2`
- `col3, col4`
- `col1, col4`

There's no single index that can satisfy these needs - if you e.g. had an index on `col1, col2, col4`, that would likely be used for query #1, but it **cannot** really be used for query #3 (or only to handle the `col1` in the beginning - but it won't help with  `col4`).

So in your case, the only option is to have **three separate** indexes - one for each type of query - and see if these really help to speed up your queries. This however also means there are **three indexes** that need to be updated and maintained, whenever the table gets insert, update or delete operations. Try and measure and then decide if the speed increase warrants possible additional overhead on insert, update and delete operations.

Comment: my doubt is if i have an index1 consist of column1 and column4 . Is this index used while execute select * from table1 where column1='some'   @marc_s

Comment: **YES!** If you have an index on `col1, col4`, it can be used for queries that include `col1=... AND col4 = ...`, but **also** for queries that have `WHERE col1 = ...` alone. If you use the **n left-most columns** - then the index will be considered by the query optimizer

Comment: so, you are telling that col1 will consider . but col4 will not consider . right ? @marc_s  . please acknowledge

Comment: If you have an index on `(col1, col4)`, then any query that has **both** columns in its WHERE clause might use this index - as will any query that uses just `col1` in its WHERE clause. But if you have a query that uses **only** `col4`, that index can **NEVER EVER** be used

Comment: ok , let me narrate an example . please tell it is correct or not.?    i created col1 as clustered index and create non clustered index for all columns  NOTE: In non clustered index i had col1 as last means . it is best idea ? bcz it takes all columns for indexing except col1  . after it takes  clustered index and it will integrate  right ? @marc_s

Comment: @Padhu: sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. CAn you either post another new question, or update your existing question and show us some code (like how you created the index(es) )? Also: the **clustering key** (the column or columns in the **clustered index**) are always automatically already part of each and every single nonclustered index - usually there's no need to add those explicitly

Answer (score 0):

If you optimize only those queries and you dont care about the size of indexes, then **yes** create them exacly like that - `(col1, col2)`, `(col3, col4)` and `(col1, col4)`. Note, that the order of columns here is unimportant.

But if you have lots of data, or you modify your data often (insert, update of the keys or delete), than you also should take that into acount. Rearanging of index takes time as well and the more columns, the more rearanging (and less options for the sql server). Indexes also takes space, so if you have big data (and limited edition or disk), than you might need to optimize space as well.

You could then choose a **trade-off** solution and create just two indexes `(col1)` and `(col4)` which would partly cover all three queries. It all depends on the selectivity of `col1` and `col4` and how often you call the queries and how fast you need them to be.

To understand the basics, see the [best guide](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree) to indexes out there.

Comment: The order of the columns ***IS*** important since it determines for which other possible queries the index might be used. If you have an index on `(col1, col4)` - then this might be used also for a query only on  `col1` - but ***NOT*** for a query only on `col4` . The order of the columns of a compound index ***IS EXTREMELY*** important!

Comment: @marc_s sure the order is important, but not **here**, by which I mean queries in **question**.

Comment: Agreed - for those three queries, it's not - but you should always think beyond what you currently have and see if you can optimize your indexes for future and additional requirements

Comment: @marc_s lets say aditional, not future (unless you know it and I bow before you than :).